# Unknown error - sonar eclipse plugin

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I have installed the sonar eclipse plugin in eclipse Juno. I put the groupid and the artifactid into the proper lines, however I get an error:

> Unknown exception

How to configure the sonar plugin properly in eclipse?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install Sonar on a server (or run it on your machine for testing). Then you need to configure it in the Eclipse properties and choose it from the drop-down in the associate with sonar dialog (unless it runs on your machine, in which case it is already available from the drop down).

Before you can associate a project with sonar, you need to run the sonar analysis on that project (usually using maven). Take a look at the [sonar documentation](http://www.sonarsource.org/support/documentation/) to get more information.